# Circumvent DS-Lite restrictions to allow incoming IPv4 request on single port

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv6, ipv4

I have recently moved, and my new ISP provides a DS-lite/carrier-NAT connection so that I do not have my 'own' IPv4 address but I'm pooled with many other people behind a single IPv4 address. As a result, I am not able to get incoming IPv4 connections; there's not even a port-forwarding option in the modem/router (I do not have a separate router). Of course, since I do have my own IPv6 address there is less of an issue there, although I'm under the impression that port forwarding does not apply to IPv6 addresses as there is no NAT for IPv6. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now comes the issue: I have some services (in particular, a PLEX server) that cannot fully function on IPv6 alone. The server is more or less able to take incoming IPv6 requests, but some of the (remote) clients can only make IPv4 requests (a mobile device on 4G; a chromecast; etc.) so these devices cannot reach the server. Moreover, the PLEX server can server content to a IPv6 address, but normally all clients try to authenticate on the IPv4 address, which is not reachable.

I have tried to cook up a list of possible circumventions:

- Use a port-mapping service like [feste-ip](https://www.feste-ip.net/) that maps all requests on a (remote) IPv4 address to a IPv6 address. I can define "custom server URL's" in the PLEX server that I believe will allow any client to reach/authenticate via this remote IPv4 address. Possible problems: limited by the network speed of the port-mapping service, the port-mapping service is a paid subscription; clients only on Ipv4 networks might still not have actual access?
- I have access to a different (remote) network, which does have it's own IPv4 address. I can try and setup a port-mapping service at this location. Possible problems: I am not certain how to perform this setup, the remote network is in a neighboring country, I won't often have on-site access for management etc., and all of the above considerations minus the paid subscription fee
- I can setup a VPN server on a raspberry pi at the remote network with it's IPv4 access, create a VPN-client docker container at my local server and attach the PLEX container to said VPN-client container. The idea/hope is that on the local network I can still access PLEX via the docker host, and that to the outside world it looks as if the PLEX server is at the remote location. The caveat here is that all outside networking for the PLEX server will be necessarily routed through the remote location.
- Bite the bullet and look for a better ISP that gives me a IPv4 address (these are exceedingly rare in my current country of residence unfortunately). Caveats: a likely higher internet subscription fee.

In anticipation of the third option I have setup a wireguard server in a docker container on a raspberry pi docker host at the remote location (I am actually there currently). If the third option is indeed the way to go, should I use Wireguard, should I use openVPN or should I ask this in a separate question?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that port forwarding does not apply to IPv6 addresses as there is no NAT for IPv6. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Yes, but more accurately, there is no *need* for NAT for IPv6.

Implementations of NAT do exist for IPv6, for dealing with some unfortunate situations (such as hosting providers who are stuck in the IPv4 mindset of charging per individual address).

But when your host has a global address for itself, NAT and port-forwarding become redundant.

> I have access to a different (remote) network, which does have it's own IPv4 address. I can try and setup a port-mapping service at this location. Possible problems: I am not certain how to perform this setup,

If all you need is HTTP and/or HTTPS, then you can use a "reverse proxy" which accepts requests over IPv4 (like a web server would) then relays them to your PLEX server over IPv6. This requires the proxy to have both IPv4 and IPv6.

Responses will be going back through the same relay as well – that's unavoidable.

> I can setup a VPN server on a raspberry pi at the remote network [...] The caveat here is that all outside networking for the PLEX server will be necessarily routed through the remote location.

That is not a requirement for VPNs. You can have the 'default' route pointing through the local ISP, while still being able to receive connections and send replies through the VPN connection. If your server runs Linux, search for "policy routing" and "ip rule add".

> If the third option is indeed the way to go, should I use Wireguard, should I use openVPN

Doesn't really matter; both will easily provide the needed functionality, as will most other VPNs.

However, if you are using Wireguard, you might need to avoid *wg-quick* as it'll probably interfere with "policy routing" setup (or at least to convince it to stop automatically adding unwanted routes, I think the option was `RouteTable = 0`.).

Comment: Thank you very much. If I may - I'd like to ask two small follow up questions.
- When going with the reverse proxy option, am I correctly understanding that this would be running on a host on the 'remote' network? And it's a no-go in the case of the remote network being IPv4-only, correct?

Comment: Yes, and yes – if the remote site is IPv4-only you basically end up doing option 3 in any case. (I would rent a cheap VPS for this purpose, though I don't know what kind of traffic limit Plex demands.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will take a look into the VPS, it might be better suited; Plex will mostly be limited by my upload speed anyhow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Rinetd on a VPS for your usecase.
The configuration is also very simple:
/etc/rinetd.conf
`(IPv4 of your Server) port/protocol (IPv6 of your Homeserver) port/protocol`

for example:
`127.0.0.1 80/tcp :: 80/tcp`

Comment: Heads up, it is normal to declare your affiliation (or not) with a link (page or software).